# Selecting data between a time range in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, date-range

I am trying to select data for multiple ID's between a time range using pyspark.

I have four columns in a spark dataframe 'event_df'

| ID | Time | Event_Start_Date | Event_End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 241856 | 2020-10-18T09:16:49.000+0000 | 2020-11-12T20:15:00.000+0000 | 2020-11-12T20:45:00.000+0000 |

In 'Time' there is data worth 2 months for individual ID's. Different ID's have different event start and end datetimes  However, I want to select data only **between** 'event start date' and 'event end date'.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to return what I want

```
 refined_df = event_df.where(( col ('Time') >= col ('Event_Start_Date')) & ( col ('Time') <= col ('Event_End_Date ')) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your line isn't working for you, but you can also try using between:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [(241856, '2020-10-18T09:16:49.000+0000', '2019-11-12T20:15:00.000+0000', '2020-11-12T20:45:00.000+0000'),
       (241857, '2020-10-18T09:16:49.000+0000', '2020-11-12T20:15:00.000+0000', '2020-11-12T20:45:00.000+0000')]

df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(['ID','Time','Event_Start_Date','Event_End_Date'])

df.show()
df.filter(F.col('Time').between(F.col('Event_Start_Date'), F.col('Event_End_Date'))).show()
```

returns

```
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    ID|                Time|    Event_Start_Date|      Event_End_Date|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|241856|2020-10-18T09:16:...|2019-11-12T20:15:...|2020-11-12T20:45:...|
|241857|2020-10-18T09:16:...|2020-11-12T20:15:...|2020-11-12T20:45:...|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+

+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|    ID|                Time|    Event_Start_Date|      Event_End_Date|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|241856|2020-10-18T09:16:...|2019-11-12T20:15:...|2020-11-12T20:45:...|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```